# Why dont people use C++ for GUI as much as the Console Application?

Tags: c++, .net, user-interface, console-application

So im currently learning C++ as my second language.. Moving over from C# because I feel like C++ is a good toolset to have.

Now I know the basics and what not so I decided to create my first application which would be a string & byte array encrypter.. Basically a application with a simple GUI a few buttons, textboxes etc etc..
So I started looking at some opensource projects for something like this and ALL the ones I found were made as a console application? And I just find this very weird because most of the C# projects that I look up are 90% made with a GUI and not console based.

Why do people use the console applications to create projects? Is there something I should know before wandering in further into this new language?

Comment: Note: This is a 'opinion' style question....  It will probably be closed soon because it's not really what this site is focused on and this kind of question sparks silly debate.

Comment: My personal opinion: the more abstract and graphical a language is (e.g. C# over C++) the quicker development in it can become.   C# is faster than C++ at making interfaces, so more people use C# to make interfaces.  However, with that abstraction comes less programmatic efficiency.  Therefore, it makes a lot of sense to use C++ (or even C or assembly in truly performance critical applications) when you have time and money and expertise to pay attention to that level of detail.  But some of the time, 'quicker development with performance-expensive memory management' is a better solution.

Comment: C# with GUI, so I'm going to assume you are on Windows. Have a look at [Learn to Program for Windows in C++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381399.aspx) for a quick introduction. It's not necessarily hard to write Windows GUI's in plain C++, but it's certainly extremely tedious to do so. Recommendation: Learn it. Once you know how to do it, pick a framework that encapsulates the tedious work (e.g. WTL).

Answer (score 8):

People *do* use C++ for writing GUIs - the browser you are currently viewing this in is almost certainly mostly written in C++, as are many other complex, high-performance,  desktop applications. However, doing so is not easy. If you simply want to knock out line-of-business applications, where performance is not critical, languages like C# and Java are easier to use - this is exactly what they were designed for.

People write "console applications" (i.e. programs that don't have a complex user interface)  because for many tasks you simply do not need a GUI.  For example, a compiler or a database engine has no need for such a thing.

Comment: When you say ```People do use C++ for writing GUIs``` do you mean writing the actuall GUI like a theme?
Because I was mainly talking about using a C++ application like a WinForm application in C#.

Comment: @Jon No, I mean people use it to write GUIs via things like the the Qt framework or the Win32 API. I don't know what you mean by a "theme".

Comment: Oh so you mean like using Visual Studio and the Windows Form? with the CLR?

Comment: Standard C++ has no official bindings to WinForms, nor the CLR. On C++ you create GUIs directly calling Win32 functions or by using a third party library like Qt which might internally use either Win32 or OpenGL or whatever.

Answer (score 3):

Standard C++ includes "console" output.   It does not include any facilities for GUI.   There are various reasons for this - most notably, that a lot of devices targeted by C++ developers don't have a screen, let alone a need for GUI.

This means that anything to do with GUI in C++ makes use of a third-party library or framework, that targets the particular platform (operating system, etc) or platforms of interest.    A number of good quality libraries/frameworks exist, but they differ from each other.   Some of them are multi-platform.

When the objective is to learn C++, there is little point in trying to write a GUI program.   The student will spend more time learning about details of a specific GUI library than about C++ itself.    Learning about a GUI library is fine, but doesn't help much with learning C++.    And the learning will often only partly relevant when learning another GUI library or framework.

A student who has learned C++ (and, yes, that means writing console applications rather than GUI programs) will have a working knowledge of how code constructs (functions, type definitions, etc) fit together.   From there, it is easier to understand the documentation for a GUI framework that is written for usage in C++ development - since the documentation for such frameworks normally ASSUMES a knowledge of C++, and extends from there.

Of course, this does mean that a student of C++ - if they need to develop a GUI - has to decide what GUI framework to use.   And then there is the effort of learning it.   But it is not necessary to relearn C++ whenever one chooses to learn/use a new GUI framework.

There are a lot of tasks for which a user interface is simply not needed, and C++ does not force (or drag) a developer into writing a user interface unless they need to.   That allows attention to be focused on the "back end" of the program - the calculations it does, rather than how the results are displayed.    And when a decent GUI is put on the front of that, the result is a better system - whether that GUI is written in C++ (using a relevant framework) or some other language (using techniques to communicate between code written in different languages).    User experience is based both on the visual aspects of GUI and on how efficiently the back end supports that GUI (response times, robustness, handling or reporting back end errors, etc).   A well-designed GUI with a poorly designed back end will not work as well for the user, regardless of what language is used.    This type of thing is why a number of systems with user interface - web browsers, etc - ARE written in C or C++.   While it is easier to write a pretty GUI using other languages, it is often more difficult to get the back end functionality working efficiently as well, and C or C++ are often better for that.

Answer (score 1):

1. Why do people use the console applications to create projects?

   Sometime we don't need a Graphic UI, one command with arguments is enough. GUI need more time for programming.
2. Is there something I should know before wandering in further into this new language?

   C++ is not the best choice for GUI in my opinion. You need to think about your platform, Windows, Mac, Linux or Browser. There are other better choices like Java which provided good UI libs and thanks to the JVM for platform adapting. Browser(Web app) is another area which is amazing too, and yes Javascript is the King.